# Sylius Resource 403 access denied

Tags: php, sylius

I've created a new bundle for adding some delivery periods for certain zones.

```
sylius_resource:
  resources:
    shop.deliveryperiods:
      classes:
        model: Shop\Bundle\DeliveryBundle\Entity\DeliveryPeriod
        form:
          default: Shop\Bundle\DeliveryBundle\Form\Type\DeliveryPeriodType
        controller: Shop\Bundle\DeliveryBundle\Controller\Backend\DeliveryController
```

I've also added this to my routing:

```
shop_backend_deliveryperiods:
    resource: |
        alias: shop.deliveryperiods
        path: deliveryperiods
    type: sylius.resource
    prefix: /administration
```

Created my entity, Configuration.php, ShopDeliveryExtension.php and all, but when I now want to open the list or edit a deliveryperiod, I get a 403 Access Denied on those pages?

Comment: Quick defining a route automatically check for permissions. You can add them to db, for the role. Probably the best way is to write them in config as in  `sylius.yml` (search rbac), and then running `php app/console sylius:rbac:initialize` -- but don't know for sure. If you write your routes separatelly you can use config: permission: false

Answer (score 0):

I indeed had to add all new routes to the permissions in Sylius. Didn't know that until now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should configure RBAC.

See Sylius dedicated documentation : http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusRbacBundle/setup.html